# Get CST Time on spring/summer with JodaTime

Tags: java, datetime, time, timezone, jodatime

It's summer now. So we have dayLightTime on. But following code doesn't take into account it or is wrong in somewhat else.

```
DateTimeZone dateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now(dateTimeZone);
System.out.println("Current time is: " + dateTime);
```

Please run this code on your machine and check output with [this](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/usa/central-time/)

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`America/New_York` is in Eastern Time.

For Central Time, use `America/Chicago`.

Comment: Wow! Many Thanks! You opened my eyes!